# If Else Java Syntax Issue

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

I am facing a very basic issue with my logic. Basically I have 2 conditions. One is when !quiet and the other is when its `!quiet && _cmdLine.isInteractive`.

I have tried to put them in an if else block but with the else I get a syntax error, and if I use just if statements or if-else if, it does not work. I have pasted my code below and need some help. I just cant figure out where I am going wrong on this.

```
if (!quiet) {
        String targetName = getPrintoutNameFromStartable(start,
                    picoName);
        System.out.print("message here");
}

if (_cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
        System.out.println("a different message");

        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the `else` version having syntax error ?

Comment: An `&&` would be a nested `if`. Because `if` one is `true` you'd still need to see `if` the other one is too. But you shouldn't have to do it like that.

Comment: You want them in an _if **else**_ condition? Don't you think one (`!quiet && _cmdLine.isInteractive`) is the subset of the other (`!quiet`)?

Comment: this is the else i tried to use

Comment: Did you do `} else if (condition` ?

Comment: But there's no `else` there.

Comment: } else {
                (!quiet) {
                    String targetName = getPrintoutNameFromStartable(start,
                            picoName);
                    System.out.print("message here");
                    
                }
            }

Comment: @samujoe where is the `if` in your else block?

Comment: yes i tried an else if condition, but an else if causes it not to work correctly

Comment: if ( _cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
                System.out.println("if is here");
                
                return 1;

Comment: @samujoe if `!quiet` is false, then `!quiet && _cmdLine.isInteractive` must be false.

Comment: @samujoe show us where you used  `else` and the used `if`

Comment: if ( _cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
                System.out.println("msg");
     
                return 1;

            } else {
                (!quiet) {
                    String targetName = getPrintoutNameFromStartable(start,
                            picoName);
                    System.out.print("another");
                 
                }
            }

Comment: @samujoe I still cannot see an `if` after your `else`

Comment: this is the if else i tried with a syntax error

Comment: @samujoe why don't you try my suggestion of putting `if` before your condition.

Comment: @samujoe your first condition has an `if` before, but your second condition has nothing. You need to put `if` in front of that too. Just like you did in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this Helps you understand how to handle two different flags.

```
if (!quiet) {
    String targetName = getPrintoutNameFromStartable(start,
        picoName);
    System.out.print("message here");

    if ( _cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
        System.out.println("a different message");
        return 1;
    }else{
        //do something
    }
}else{
    if ( !_cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
        System.out.println("a different message");
        return 1;
    }else{
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this out, exactly the same, but it does not work

Comment: thats y i tried to switch to an if else

Comment: Why do you believe "it does not work"? You have said anything which would indicate why it shouldn't.

Comment: I think it should be
           
              if (!quiet) {
                       if ( _cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
                                System.out.println("a different message");

                             return 1;
                         }
                      String targetName = getPrintoutNameFromStartable(start,
                    picoName);
                 System.out.print("message here");

                  }

Comment: if you can post your complete method, maybe we can try to help. although this is spoonfeeding already

Comment: if samu confirms i will change the answer

Comment: I mean I tried out this same code before, and it causes my application to not behave correctly. The scenario A happens if !quiet and scenario B if its interactive. If I try it like that I can only get 1 scenario and not both, thus my dilemma

Comment: I can post the entire method, but its really long. The only part I am stuck on is this. Both scenarios can work individually, but not together. Its either !quiet works or interactive works. But not together

Comment: I think you're being pressured into issues. Looks like if "a different message" shouldn't be "another different message" on the second one you have needless logic.

Comment: I tried the solution by MozenRath, but It does not work, it causes only 1 method to be executed and the other does not. They r both supposed to work for 2 different scenarios

Comment: now i am getting a null pointer exception

Comment: sorry but this now beyond my patience

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
if (!quiet && _cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
    // ...
} else if (!quiet) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't that technically redundant?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils else if executes if _cmdLine.isInteractive() is false.

Comment: What I mean is, checking `!quiet` twice is technically redundant. When `quiet` is `true` it fails both asap. When `quiet` is `false` you already knew it was `true`. Not a down voter btw.

Comment: if (_cmdLine.isInteractive()) {
                System.out.println("Command not supported in interactive mode");
                Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME).log(Level.WARNING, "Zoom");
                // return 1;

            }


         if (!quiet) {
                String targetName = getPrintoutNameFromStartable(start,
                        picoName);
                System.out.print(S_SHUTTING + targetName + "...");
                Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME).log(Level.WARNING, "Original method");

            }

Comment: i get a java null pointer exception when trying this